# how to markdown multiple email blade?

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5

i have multiple email template blade view which i want to markdown but laravel defualt mail method have one build method like this

```
   /**
 * Build the message.
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function build()
{
    return $this->markdown('view-to-mail', [
            'messageBody' => $this->data['message'],
        ]);
}
```

**but i have multiple email template like this**

```
  mail1.blade.php
    mail2.blade.php
    mail3.blade.php
```

i wnat to make all of them as markdown **something** like this

```
    public function build()
{
    return $this->markdown('mail1.blade.php', [
            'messageBody' => $this->data['message'],
        ]);
    return $this->markdown('mail2.blade.php', [
            'messageBody' => $this->data['message'],
        ]);
    return $this->markdown('mail3.blade.php', [
            'messageBody' => $this->data['message'],
        ]);
}
```

**how i can do that something like above?**